# how can i search for common elements in two integers with while loop

Tags: python, algorithm, list, while-loop

in my code im having a problem because i cannot compare to list as i wanted. what i try to do is looking for first indexes of inputs firstly and then if indexes not the same looking for the next index of the longer input as i guess1. and then after finishing comparing the first index of elements i want to compare second indexes .. what i mean first checking (A-C)(A-A)(A-T) and then (C-A)(C-T).. and then (T-T)...
and want an input list as (A,T) beacuse of ATT part of guess1..
however i stuck in a moment that i always find ACT not A and T..
where i am wrong.. i will be very glad if you enlighten me..

edit..
what i'm trying to do is looking for the best similarity  in the longer list of guess1 and find the most similiar list as ATT

```
GUESS1="CATTCG"
GUESS2="ACT"
if len(str(GUESS1))>len(str(GUESS2)):
        DNA_input_list=list((GUESS1))
        DNA_input1_list=list((GUESS2))
        common_elements=[]
        i=0
        while i<len(DNA_input1_list)-1:
            j=0
            while j<len(DNA_input_list)-len(DNA_input1_list):
                if DNA_input_list[i] == DNA_input1_list[j]:
                    common_elements.append(DNA_input1_list[j])
                    i+=1
                j+=1
                if j>len(DNA_input1_list)-1:
                    break
        print(common_elements)
```

Comment: so your trying to find index of `GUESS2` to see if its in the `GUESS1`? So your trying to find duplicates in two different lists?

Comment: Your code is far from self-explanatory and your question text doesn't help much. Can you rephrase and explain more simply what you're trying to do?

Comment: thanx for the answer..actually what i m trying to do is looking for similarity of two list and i'm trying this way.. i mean i want the program searching as the length of the guess 2 and returns the most similiar list

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by most similar but your code is finding `A`, `C` and `T` which are in both list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to find a shorter substring in a longer substring, and if not found, remove an element from shorter substring then repeat the search.

You can use string find function in python for that. i.e. `"CATTCG".find('ACT')`, this function will return -1 because there are no substing ACT. What then you can do is remove an element from the shorter string using slice operator `[::]` and repeat the search like this --

```
>>> for x in range(len('ACT')):
...     if "CATTCG".find('ACT'[x:]) > -1 :
...             print("CATTCG".find('ACT'[x:]))
...             print("Match found for " + 'ACT'[x:])
```

In code here, first a range of lengths is generated i.e. [0, 1, 2, 3] this is the number of items we're gonna slice off from the beginning.

In second line we do the slicing with 'ACT'[x:] (for x==0, we get 'ACT', for x == 1, we get 'CT' and for x==2, we get 'T').

The last two lines print out the position and the string that matched.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood everything correctly, you want to return the longest similar substring from GUESS2, with is included in GUESS1.

I would use something like this.

```
<!-- language: lang-py -->
for count in range(len(GUESS2)):
       if GUESS2[:count] in GUESS1:
               common_elements = GUESS2[:count]
print(GUESS2[:count]) #if a function, return GUESS2[:count]
```

A loop as long as the count from the searching string.
Then check if the substring is included in the other.
If so, save it to a variable and print/return it after the loop has finished.